# How can I resolve an issue with a github code space for C?

Tags: c, github, github-codespaces

Hello I am new to coding I'm currently doing the Harvard cs50x course and we use a code space on GitHub for C and it is no longer loading properly. It either loads fast and I am met with a white background, all the code being normal text, and I can not type in the terminal.
Example:
[Code space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWe0S.png)

If it does not load fast it will be loading for a while and I will receive this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSVSp.png) I am really new to programming so any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this a problem with the Webpage?

Comment: I'd say, ask the cs50x folks or GitHub support. It has a little to do with your or our programming skills.

Comment: oh ok, I thought I might have broken something cause I was working with memory earlier.

Comment: If I understand correctly, these "codespaces" are cloud-based sandboxes, which should be very hard to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood the problem correctly, but if you just want to test simple code while the course platform doesn't work properly, you can also use a free online C compiler like the one [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) or even download a local compiler on your machine for more sophisticated programs in the future and not be at the mercy of online platforms like [CodeBlocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/) or [Dev-C++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/).

Anyway, regardless of your choice, it is also recommended to contact the course team to ensure how you can proceed in the face of error on the teaching platform.

Hope you can keep up in your learning process!

Comment: Ps.: Keep in mind also that normally local compilers return exactly the type of error that happened while trying to compile their code -depending on the compiler, they can even show which part of the code generated the error, or even give suggestions to solve it-, so searching for the error code on the internet turns out to be a lot easier overall.

Comment: I think the servers were down because a little while later it started to work so all is good.

Comment: could you recommend some local compilers for python as it is the other language I want to focus on

Comment: Sure @bing bong but keep in mind that the programming paradigm of C and python are different, as is their level of access to machine language, so in C we use compilers while in python we use IDE's (Integreted Development Environment). Personally I recommend you to download python through the Anaconda package which will come for free with several different options for you to program like the IDE's Spyder and VisualStudio Code

Comment: Oh, and about python you can also check online for Jupyter Notebooks tips, a simple and intuitive environment to program, test and learn more about the language in a very dynamic way (which will also be included in the anaconda package)